# Is it possible to check if a file exists on disk using Javascript (not running in a browser)?

Tags: javascript, file-io

I am using an app that uses **only** JavaScript as its scripting language. I have a `.ini` file and I need to see if it exists. Is this possible?

Also, if it doesn't exist, how can I halt the execution?

Comment: what app are you using? it depends on what they provide for you.

Comment: As long as Javascript is not running in the server, then it might be possible to do that. But I need to know the OS that you are targeting.?

Comment: Sorry it's Win7. Also the app I use doesn't give any extra functionality other than controlling the app, which are stuff like adding effects, text on an image, resize image, delete layers, etc. But no generic file IO or libs.

Comment: it would be helpful to know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok doing something like this works:

```
var file = new File(datafile);
var result = file.open ('r');
```

if `result` is `true`, then the file exists, otherwise `false` means the file does not exist.

Comment: Can you provide some documentation for this File object? What environment is it used in?

Comment: SpiderMonkey ([https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/File_object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/File_object)) and Adobe ExtendScript.

Answer (score 1):

"Yes", assuming ActiveX can be used.

See [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) aka "FSO" (the [FileExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method in particular). FSO is part of Windows Scripting.

It is also possible to use the MSXML  [load method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to access a "file://" and catch the *appropriate* error. (I don't know if a vanilla XmlHttpRequest request of "file://" can be used here, and/or in what contexts... it might differ between the XHR from MSXML and the one baked into IE7/8 as well.)

Happy coding.

---

If the JavaScript runs from an [HTA/HTML Aplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) or Windows Sidgebar Gadget, etc, then it's in "Security Level 0" or "Demigod Mode".

> > On the other hand, an *HTA runs as a fully trusted application* and therefore has more privileges than a normal HTML file...

Comment: Thanks I tried this var `fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");` but it says activexobject doesn't have a constructor.

Comment: @Joan Venge Perhaps Photoshop does not support ActiveX, or perhaps the syntax is different.

Comment: I don't think it supports ActiveX, I will look it up. But is this not possible without using ActiveX?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var myfile = new File(myfile_path);

if (!myfile.exists) {
    alert(myfile + " could not be found!");
}
```