# Determine if file exists or is 0 Bytes

Tags: javascript, photoshop, exists, extendscript, photoshop-script

In Photoshop I can read in a text file.

```
function does_file_exist(f)
{
    var lines = "";
    var aFile = new File(f);
    aFile.open("r");
    while(!aFile.eof)
    {
     var line = aFile.readln();
     if (line != null && line.length >0)
     {
        lines += line + "\n";
     }
    }
    aFile.close();

    if (lines.length == 0)
    {
        alert(f + "\ndoes not exist!");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        var trunc = lines.substring(0,256);
        alert(f + " exists!\nHere's proof:\n\n" + trunc + "...")
        return lines;
    }
}
```

If the string returned has a length of 0 we assume that the file simply doesn't exist. This works fine, but what happens if there is an empty file of 0 bytes? Can I access the filesize properties? Or is there another way around this problem? There seem to be problems with file.exists()

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/7340313/989920?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Error 22: ActiveXObject does not have a constructor. No, ActiveX doesn't help - nice try though ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File(f).exists
```

Is a Boolean not a function

> Boolean exists Read only Property
>   If true, this object refers to a file or file-system alias that actually exists in the file system.

**Update:** Actually "Mr. Mystery Guest" is right (see comments).

```
File('~/Desktop/does-not-exist.txt').exists
```

returns true for me on macOS 10.12.2 and PS CC2017 even though the file does not exists. Using

```
new File('~/Desktop/does-not-exist.txt').exists
```

seems to work as excepted.

**Update 2:**

This error seems to be a Photoshop specific problem. In ESTK and in InDesign `File('~/Desktop/does-not-exist.txt').exists` returns false

Comment: Tell that to Adobe :)

Comment: Which photoshop and os are you on?

Comment: Photoshop CC (1.4.2.1) x64 Win 7

Comment: `File('~/Desktop/does-not-exist.txt').exists` returns true for me on macOS 10.12.2 and PS CC2017 :-( but 
`new File('~/Desktop/does-not-exist.txt').exists` seems to work as excepted.

Comment: D'oh! I've seen where I've gone wron. Small confusion over the keyword"FIle" `var someTextFile = "c:\\temp\\textfile.txt";
alert(File(someTextFile ).exists); //true`